# Trying to access private class variables in header function

Tags: c++, class, header-files

I need several functions in a header file that use `std::cout` to say the date, but I don't know how to access them from the header file. If I were within the class, I could just say something like:

```
 void  DisplayStandard()
    {
        cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;
    }
```

However, since I'm accessing month, day, and year (which are privates in my .cpp file) I'm not sure how to modify those from void functions in the implementation file. Here's all the code:

dateclasses.h

```
#ifndef DATECLASS_H
#define DATECLASS_H

class dateclass
{
    private:
        int month;
        int day;
        int year;
    public:
        //default constructor
        dateclass()
        {
            month = 1;
            day = 1;
            year = 1;
        }
        //value constructor
        dateclass(int month, int day, int year) 
        {
            this->month = month;
            this->day = day;
            this->year = year;
        }
        void DisplayStandard(); 
    
};
#endif
```

dateclasses.cpp

```
#include "dateclass.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void DisplayStandard()
{
    cout << "Date: " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;
}
```

I have yet to set up the main function, though I don't think it necessary for this

Comment: `void DisplayStandard() { ... }` defines a ***non***-member function. How do your book or tutorial say a class member function is defined?

Comment: Use `dateclass::DisplayStandard` to refer to the member function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **solve** this by changing `void DisplayStandard()` to `void dateclass::DisplayStandard()` as shown below

```
void dateclass::DisplayStandard()//note the dateclass:: added infront of DisplayStandard
{
    cout << "Date: " << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;
}
```

Comment: thank you! this is my second time taking this course and header files were never something that made sense to me--very helpful